# Missing __RequestVerificationToken to bypass google captcha with external solver

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, recaptcha, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some sites that require to solve a captcha for login, the best way I have found to do it so is to use an external service like https://anti-captcha.com/ which have a person on the other site solving the captchas and sends back a hash value to verify the result.

As in the documentation, the process is:

1. I send the site url and sitekey

[image]

2. They assign the task to some worker and after a one or two mins I get back the hash value to login

**The issue is** That the actual request I need to make requires two other values besides that one:

```
* __RequestVerificationToken: This one appears on the login page:
```

[image]

But the value that is sent through the login request is different, so there is some work in the middle that I'm missing

```
* RecaptchaToken: There is no trace of this value in the login site, I'm suspecting it may be generated in the back end as an additional verification step, but I have not found any information about it.
```

My last concern regarding this process, is that the anti-captcha service seems to be solving some generic captcha, and not the same that I'm seem, not sure if that is an actual issue though.

Comment: What kind of captcha? Image to decode?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are talking about reCAPTCHA v2, which ask the user to select certain images with some object in it.

### how it works:

based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)
after the user solve the recaptcha images puzzle, he clicks "verify", this sends a post request to google api, to this url: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
with the user response to the puzzle -encoded ofc- and it gets a response, called "g-recaptcha-response" which is used to identify if the user response/solution to the puzzle is correct or not.

so mainly standard recaptcha v2, only need 1 token to validate the user response, but this is not the case you are facing here, ***you are facing a custom implementation*** that intended especially to make it harder to scrape or crawl these sites by unwanted parties.

they have developed **2 extra tokens** that are uniquely generated and injected to the page that shows the captcha puzzle, and by sending those extra tokens they are making sure that the "g-recaptcha-response" is coming from the same page that the user already loaded in his browser.

you need to inject the g-recaptcha-response you have from this api that solves the recaptcha for you in the same page you are visiting, then simulate the complete user interaction with the page.

I recommend you to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), it will help you automate all user actions and also inject everything you need to the page DOM.